# Trying to prove $\forall m \in N$, $\exists j \in N$, ($m^2 = 3j-2$) $\vee$ ($m^2 = 3j$)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove $\forall m \in N$, $\exists j \in N$, ($m^2 = 3j-2$) $\vee$ ($m^2 = 3j$) , however I've tried several proof by cases where $m$ is even or odd but I can't seem to prove it.

When $m=$ even, let $m = 2k$ for some $k$.

LHS: $\frac{(2k)^2+2}{3}$ = $\frac{2(k^2+1)}{3}$ = $j$ which is not possible since $j$ $\in$ N

RHS: $\frac{4k^2}{3}$ = $j$ which also not possbile

Same goes for when $m=$ odd.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Instead of separating into cases where $m$ is divisible by $2$ or not, separate into cases where $m$ is divisible by $  3$ or not

Answer (score 1):

Work with $m$ modulo $3$, not $2$. If $m=3k$, take $j=3k^2$; if $m=3k\pm1$, take $j=3k^2\pm2k+1$.

Comment: why would $m=3k+1$ or $3k-1$

Comment: @ph-quiett That exhausts the cases where $3\nmid m$. If $m=3k^\prime+2$, write $k=k^\prime+1$.

Answer (score 0):

This means that every square is congruent to $-2$ ($\equiv 1$) or $0\mod 3$.

This results from any integer being congruent to $1,-1$ or $0\mod 3$, and congruences being compatible with multiplication.

Comment: I don't get how that would prove the statement

Comment: If $m\equiv \pm 1$, then $m^2\equiv 1^2=1\equiv 2\mod 3$. If $m\equiv 0$, $m^2\equiv 0^2=0\mod 3$. Isn't it clear?,

Comment: sorry I can't seem to wrap my head around how that concludes the proof

Comment: Think what a congruence means: divisible by $3$, for instance, is the same as congruent to $0\bmod 3$.

Answer (score 0):

If $m$ is divisible by $3$, then $m^2$ is.

If not, then $m-1$ or $m+1$ is, so $m^2+2=(m+1)(m-1)+3$ is.

Comment: $x$ is divisible by $3$ means $\exists j\in. \Bbb N$ such that $x=3j$